# Freenet Message System don't work when i start with bash script

Tags: bash, localhost

I try start [FMS](http://127.0.0.1:8888/freenet:USK@0npnMrqZNKRCRoGojZV93UNHCMN-6UU3rRSAmP6jNLE,%7EBG-edFtdCC1cSH4O3BWdeIYa8Sw5DfyrSV-TKdO5ec,AQACAAE/fms/151/download.htm) to [Freenet](https://freenetproject.org/) it's localhost:8080 so if i had start this without .sh script everything works, but when i start this with .sh script, it show me(console and there is maintenance...):

```
[sudo] password for gooder: Started DB Maintenance Thread : 1
Started HTTP Thread : 2
Started NNTP Thread : 3
Started Freenet FCP Thread : 4
FMS has been started.
```

in browser localhost:8080 :

Could not open template.htm! Place in /home/gooder/ and restart!

So this is my bash script:

```
echo -e "password" | sudo -S /home/gooder/Documents/Scripts/Fms/fms
```

I'll try to debug:

```
[gooder@GOD Scripts]$ sh --debugger fms.sh 
fms.sh: /usr/share/bashdb/bashdb-main.inc: No such file or directory
fms.sh: warning: cannot start debugger; debugging mode disabled
Started DB Maintenance Thread : 1
Started HTTP Thread : 2
Started NNTP Thread : 3
Started Freenet FCP Thread : 4
FMS has been started.
```

I'll try start just:

```
[gooder@GOD ~]$ sudo /home/gooder/Documents/Scripts/Fms/fms
```

and it doesn't work

```
[sudo] password for gooder: 
Started DB Maintenance Thread : 2
Started HTTP Thread : 3
Started NNTP Thread : 4
Started Freenet FCP Thread : 5
FMS has been started.
```

Download this fms in clearnet :) - https://mega2.dp.ua/ru/2GXf

Comment: How do you start it habitually? with `/home/gooder/Documents/Scripts/Fms/fms`?

Comment: With bash script in /home/gooder/Documents/fms.sh

Comment: And yes i start habitually this  /home/gooder/Documents/Scripts/Fms/fms (wtihout bash script)

Comment: A workaround could be : `sudo -S echo <<< 'password' && /home/gooder/Documents/Scripts/Fms/fms`

Comment: @Fravadona ehh same

`gooder@GOD Scripts]$ sh fms.sh 

Access to file denied: fms.log`

and than from sudo

`[gooder@GOD Scripts]$ sudo sh fms.sh 

Started DB Maintenance Thread : 1
Started HTTP Thread : 2
Started NNTP Thread : 3
Started Freenet FCP Thread : 4
FMS has been started.`

Also not work

Comment: what is `fms.sh`?  the script were you hardcoded your password for echoing it to `sudo -S`?

Comment: @Fravadona Yes,it is begin: write password and the next open /home/gooder/Documents/Scripts/Fms/fms (is this work to another my programs i had started with script bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! I changed my script like this, and it works:

```
cd /home/gooder/Documents/Scripts/Fms/
sudo -S echo <<< 'password' && ./fms
```

Thanks to the contribution in the comments.